# calculating some limits with elementary ways

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How the following limits can be computed without using Taylor series, Laurent series, or L'Hospital?

**I)**
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/4} \frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)}{\cos\left(2x\right)}$$

**II)**
$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{a^{x}-x^{a}}{x-a}$$

**III)**

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1+3^{x}\right)}{\ln\left(1+2x\right)}$$

**IV)**
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{a^{x}}$$
my try:

about the first one :

since $\ln\left(x\right)$ is continuous over its domain hence the limit can be written as:

$$=\ln\left(\lim_{x\to\pi/4}\tan\left(x\right)^{^{\frac{1}{\cos\left(2x\right)}}}\right)=\ln\left(e^{\lim_{x\
to\pi/4}\large{\frac{\left(\tan\left(x\right)-1\right)}{\cos\left(2x\right)}}}\right)$$

this is where do I have a problem, how can I compute the limit just by some elementary ways?
for the second and forth one I tried to use substitution but that does not work.

about the second case I applied the same strategy used for the first one,but I have the same problem

Comment: Can you compute derivatives? Then writing $\frac{\tan(x) - 1}{\cos (2x)}$ as $\frac{\tan(x) - 1}{x - \pi/4}\cdot \frac{x-\pi/4}{\cos (2x)}$ helps. And for the second, add a convenient $0$ (namely. $-a^a + a^a$) to the numerator.

Comment: Below I showed how to compute the limit in the exponent of e.

Answer (score 0):

For the first limit, it can be made much simpler, with only high-school tools:

Set $t=\tan x\;$ ($t\to 1$ as $x\to\frac\pi 4$), so that the limit becomes, using some trigonometry, the limit, as $t\to 1$, of:
$$\frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)}{\cos\left(2x\right)}= \frac{\ln t}{\cfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}=\frac{(1+t^2)\ln t}{1-t^2}=\underbrace{\frac{1+t^2}{1+t}}_{\downarrow\\1} \cdot\underbrace{\frac{\ln t}{1-t}}_{\;\downarrow\\-1}$$

Comment: very nice answer

Answer (score 0):

Or:
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/4} \frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)}{\cos\left(2x\right)}=
\lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{\ln (\tan (x))}{1-\tan x}\cdot \lim_{x\to \pi/4}\frac{1-\tan x}{\cos 2x}=(-1)\cdot 1=-1,$$
where:
$$\small 1) \ \ \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\ln x}{1-x}=-1\\
\small 2) \ \ \lim_{x\to \pi/4}\frac{1-\tan x}{\cos 2x}=\lim_{x\to \pi/4} \frac{1-\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}{(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos x+\sin x)}=\lim_{x\to \pi/4} \frac{1}{\cos x(\cos x+\sin x)}=1.$$